# line breaks on comments textareas

Tags: php

A user post a comment on a forum using a textarea, he presses enter to format his text which means line breaks, how can I convert those line breaks to html breaks when inserting its message on the database so the message is echoed with the line breaks formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function called `nl2br()`. Use it when echoing data, not when inserting to database. You don't want to display those `<br/>` tags when the user opens their post in textarea for editing, do you?

Answer (score 1):

Use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

It will convert new lines to `<br>`, so html will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function. It replaces all newlines within a string with html br tags.

For example (taken from php manpage):

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```

Outputs:

```
foo isn't<br />
 bar
```

The best practice is to use it when outputting data and store the data in the original ofrmat (with standard newlines).

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?:

```
 $html_text = nl2br($text);
```